# Multiple apis trigger without using settimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have calling dataUpdate function every 4 second until records length to 0.

Inside the dataUpdate this.callAPI();  is trigger api call.

I set manual timeout for 4 seconds to call the function to callapi.

Instead of timeout ,how to call the api immediately after previous api completed.

```
 dataUpdate =()=> { 
     var arrayList = this.arrayList; 
     if(arrayList.length > 0)
     { 
         var inputData = {
             ...inputData,
             data:{
                 ...inputData.data,first:'',second:'' 
             }
          }; 
            var first = arrayList[0].first;
            var second = arrayList[0].second; 
            inputData.data.first = first;
            inputData.data.second = second;  
            this.setState({ inputData:inputData });  
            this.callAPI(); 
            arrayList.shift();
            this.arrayList = arrayList; 
            
                if(arrayList.length !== 0){  
                    setTimeout(() => { 
                         this.dataUpdate();
                    }, 4000); 
                } 
                
                if(arrayList.length === 0){   
                    setTimeout(() => {  
                        this.props.callMessage(this.totalCount);
                    }, 1000);    
                }
                 
       } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in having state. Make callapi function stateless and pass all needed parameters so you can call it any amount of times and do not rely on previous call or state